# Matrix Translations with OpenGL Normals

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, opentk, normals

I'm working with geometry in OpenGL and I'm now working with lighting.  I'm noticing that if I translate my geometry, the normals don't follow and are thus useless.

How do you apply a tranformation matrix to geometry and maintain the normals?

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
        GL.PushMatrix();

        if (Offset != null)
        {
            GL.Translate(Offset.X, Offset.Y, Offset.Z);
        }
        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);
        foreach (var face in Faces)
        {
            foreach (var i in face)
            {
                var point = Points[i - 1];
                GL.Normal3(point);
                GL.Vertex3(point);
            }
        }
        GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();
```

When I give the geometry an offset, it doesn't render properly (e.g. the normals don't map correctly.

Any help would be excellent.

p.s., I'm using the OpenTK wrapper, but regular OpenGL translates directly across.

EDIT:

Ok, if I change the above code to the following:

```
        GL.PushMatrix();

        //if (Offset != null)
        //{
        //    GL.Translate(Offset.X, Offset.Y, Offset.Z);
        //}
        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);
        foreach (var face in Faces)
        {
            foreach (var i in face)
            {
                var point = Points[i - 1];
                if (Offset == null)
                {
                    GL.Normal3(point);
                    GL.Vertex3(point);
                }
                else
                {
                    var pt = new Vector3d(Offset.X + point.X, Offset.Y + point.Y, Offset.Z + point.Z);
                    GL.Normal3(pt);
                    GL.Vertex3(pt);
                }
            }
        }
        GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();
```

everything renders fine.

Here are some screenshots (respective to their code)

[image: Shading not working]
[image: Shading working]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do... normals are not meant to be translated. Normals are directions, they have no notion of position. That's why their _w_ component is zero.

Comment: If I have my offset set to {0,0,0}, the object renders fine, but if I change the offset at all, it screws up the Normals.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not really. In your new "working" code, the values going into your normals aren't the correct normals, as you are using pt in stead of point. They are not of length 1 (are you using GL_NORMALIZE?) and severely biased in the z-direction.

Comment: @Paul, you're right on.  I was pulling the point values, not the normal values for the points.  Blah, it looks so simple, but when you aren't thinking, you can never find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your normals are fine, but you aren't properly updating your light position and/or direction. Check out the [OpenGL FAQ Chapter 18](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/lights.htm), 18.050 in particular.

Comment: Ok, I added an update.  Let me know if that sheds some light on the matter (lol)